# How to reset iptables rate limit counter?

Tags: iptables

I implemented SSH connection rate limiting using the following.

```
iptables -N SSH_BRUTE_FORCE_MITIGATION
iptables -A SSH_BRUTE_FORCE_MITIGATION -m recent --name SSH --set
iptables -A SSH_BRUTE_FORCE_MITIGATION -m recent --name SSH --update --seconds 300 --hitcount 10 -m limit --limit 1/second --limit-burst 100 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables[ssh-brute-force]: "
iptables -A SSH_BRUTE_FORCE_MITIGATION -m recent --name SSH --update --seconds 300 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
iptables -A SSH_BRUTE_FORCE_MITIGATION -j ACCEPT
```

How can I reset rate limit counter?

**Edit:** tried `sudo iptables -Z`, but following error is thrown.

```
$ sudo iptables -Z
[sudo] password for pi:
iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables):  RULE_REPLACE failed (Invalid argument): rule in chain INPUT
```

Comment: Note that rate-limiting the ssh port is 97% security theatre. Either you use authentication methods that cannot be practically brute forced. Or your system is insecure anyway and any effort in rate limiting only makes it easier to DoS you.

Comment: Hey @anx, thanks for sharing your feedback. I always use key authentication and store keys on YubiKeys. Would you recommend not mitigating SSH brute force attacks? Btw, would love to get your feedback on the following [guide](https://sunknudsen.com/privacy-guides/how-to-configure-hardened-debian-server).

Comment: Its not a mitigation, if all it does is making it easier to prevent *you* from accessing. After disable password auth, there is no plausible attack left that could be mitigated by rate limiting. Oh and, do not follow guides on the internet that tell you to disable IPv6 or drop certain ICMP packages. There may be use cases for either, but it certainly is not a good general recommendation, security-wise. Checkout [security](https://security.stackexchange.com) for proper discussions of these 3 topics.

Comment: Btw, the guide is mine... hence why I am asking for your feedback (if ever you are down) to make it better. I am a privacy content creator... I designed a CMS where others can peer review content to make it better. Looks like you would an amazing contributor.

Comment: I am intrigued by your IPv6 recommendations btw... please [get in touch](https://sunknudsen.com/contact) if ever you have time to bounce ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reset the `-m recent --name SSH` data:

```
echo / | sudo tee /proc/net/xt_recent/SSH
```

From `man 8 iptables-extensions`, section "recent":

```
/proc/net/xt_recent/* are the current lists of addresses
 and information about each entry of each list.

Each file in /proc/net/xt_recent/ can be read from to see
 the current list or written two using the following commands to modify the list:

echo +addr >/proc/net/xt_recent/DEFAULT
    to add addr to the DEFAULT list 
echo -addr >/proc/net/xt_recent/DEFAULT
    to remove addr from the DEFAULT list 
echo / >/proc/net/xt_recent/DEFAULT
    to flush the DEFAULT list (remove all entries).
```

This is **not** the same as the per-rule packet/byte counters which can be cleared with `iptables -Z`.
This is also **not** the same as the `-m limit` (which you are using for rate-limiting the *logging*) or `-m hashlimit` counters. Those do not offer such proc interface. Possible workarounds:

1. unloading the module `xt_recent`/`xt_limit`/`xt_hashlimit` will discard the respective associated data

   - only possible while no rules are currently using it
   - needs to be built as a module - unloading builtins is not supported
2. changing the rules to use a different `--name`/`--hashlimit-name` (appending a number will do)

   - not an atomic transaction
   - depending on order of replacement, can momentarily mean in unexpected behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will try it out ASAP and report back once I confirm answer works. 